# How to remove old version python from pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with old version Python on my MacBook before I started to use Docker. I want remove all old version of Python without 3.8:
[image]

How remove from PyCharm old version of Python like: 3.7, 2.7, 3 etc.?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove old Python versions (or virtualenvs), you should go to:

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project interpreter
```

Then, click on the gear icon on the top-right corner of the window and click on "show all". 
Choose the Python Interpreter and remove it clicking the minus icon on the right side of the window.

In this way, python interpreter will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

@giordano, thank you, but I still see old version:
a) my view in project interpreters:
[image]

b) my view in add python interpreter
[image]

How delete old version python like 3.7 (red color), and python2 etc from point "b)"?

Answer (score 0):

The interpreter paths in your original screenshot define detected interpreters. The ones that are not configured in PyCharm but found on your file system. They have no name and their icons are a bit pale.

Interpreter path on the first position could be an interpreter that was used before for creating a virtual environment. This settings could be overwritten by creating new virtual environment with another base interpreter.