# PyCharm: How to fully remove old [invalid] Interpreters

Tags: python, pycharm, interpreter

I have played with PyCharm all day, now I have deleted all projects from the file system, nonetheless I still get old interpreters [invalid] that I have no way to remove, in some places mention the "gear" icon, I have no gear icon, PyCharm 2022.3:

[image]

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I mention how to remove invalid interpreters [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73998257/pycharm-ignores-new-virtual-environment-after-moving-existing-one-or-deleting-an/73998258#73998258).

Answer (score 5):

I also messed around with invalid interpreters in PyCharm, which I couldn't get rid of within PyCharm.

My solution was finally to edit `jdk.table.xml` with a text editor. In MS-Windows environments this file is located in `%APPDATA%\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\options\`

Comment: This is the FINAL solution to all the problem when you move folders with projects inside...thx

Answer (score 5):

This issue bothers me for a few days. PyCharm intermittently prompts for "Invalid python interpreter selected". The reason is that over the years I created and deleted too many projects and left lots of invalid python interpreter(created by virtual-env). Finally I was able to get all the invalid python interpreter from here:

File > New Projects Setup > Settings for New Projects... > Python Interpreter > Show All...

[image]

From there you can select and delete all the invalid interpreters!

Comment: I follow this way, however the `Show All...` option does not list the Invalid ones, really annoying.

Answer (score -1):

In the navigation menu on the left, you can see you are in the `Build, Execution, Deployment`>`Console`>`Python Console` screen, instead go in `Python Interpreter` and you will find the gear icon to do that.